# jquery breadcrumbs trail examples or Tutorial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, breadcrumbs

I am suppose to make a breadcrumb trail with jquery as my website has nested pages? I am unknown to breadcrumb and how it works if i want to add breadcrumbs dynamically to web pages?
any help or tutorial links would help

for ex: i have homepage and products page and also each product has its specific page so when i go to product pages child my breadcrumb should show something like

> Home / Product / currentpage

I want it to add dynamically to each page the user navigates

Comment: Unless this is a single page app, just do this on the back-end (with PHP, Rails, Node, or whatever you're using to serve up the site). Are you using any sort of dynamic language to serve up your HTML?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte its not big but its required as products have nested pages. can it be not done with javascript or jquery? I am using jquery and javascript with html

Comment: It can be done, but it's the wrong tool for the job, in my opinion. Are you using PHP?

Comment: Ah, okay. Is it just static HTML?

Comment: How would the JavaScript on any given page know what the breadcrumb trail should be? Is it obviously reflected in the URL of the current page? Or supplied somewhere within the current page?

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right my guess was to go with url but as i am new to it didnt know where to start

Comment: That's absolutely fine; I didn't mean to pick on you, I just wondered how we might be able to help is all. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas its okay i didnt mind it.

Comment: By structuring the source files in directories that reflect your page nesting, you should be able to parse each page's `location` client-side in javascript, and build the breadcrumb accordingly. This would be an "interesting" approach that could be made to work, though (a) every page would need to be, say, `index.htm`, and (b) all intra-site urls would (realistically) need to be relative to root `/`, not conventionally relative. Otherwise, the site would be a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29) has a good explanation on Breadcrumbs.

I recommend [jBreadCrumb](http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html) -- it's a jQuery breadcrumb plugin. And here's a [list of a few more](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2011/07/17/7-jquery-breadcrumbs-to-enhance-your-website-navigation/) jQuery breadcrumb plugins.

Hope these helps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please expand your answer to include quotes and/or text from the linked pages. Imagine that the pages you linked are changed/removed -- your answer becomes worthless in the future. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more info.