# jquery - dynamic breadcrumb

Tags: jquery, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb system for my site using the following:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="item"><a href="#home">Home / </a></div>
</div>

<div class="items">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#test1">Test 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#test1">Test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do is so when a user clicks on `Test 1` the breadcrumb is `Home / Test 1`, if they then click on `Test 2` and then `Level 1`, the breadcrumb will become `Home / Test 1 / Level 2`

I've been looking at jQuery to do this, but not 100% sure how best to approach it.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213612/jquery-breadcrumbs-trail-examples-or-tutorial

Comment: _if they then click on Test 2 and then Level 1, the breadcrumb will become Home / Test 1 / Level 2_ Shouldn't it be _Home / Test 2 / Level 1_?

Comment: @Ejay sorry was a typo. you would be correct.

Comment: Please be aware that it would make sense to approach this with javascript/jquery only if clicking the link doesn't actually send you to a different page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

example http://jsfiddle.net/mPsez/3/

```
$('.items a').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
  });
    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#home">Home</a>') );
    return false;
})
```

Comment: How would I actually replace the HTML though?

Comment: added that bit in `$('.breadcrumb a').html( bc.reverse().join(' / ') );`

Comment: What abotu having each of the breadcrumb a link? i.e. <a href="#home">Home /</a> <a href="#test1">Test 1</a> etc?

Comment: Brilliant that's exactly what I was looking for!