# Dynamic breadcrumb based on current page using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, breadcrumbs

I've looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416842/jquery-dynamic-breadcrumb) and the answer looked good enough if one doesn't have to actually navigate too.

I need a Javascript/jQuery script that, based on the URL of the current page, can create breadcrumbs with the parents of that page, IE:

```
 <nav class="items">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="test.html">Test 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="level1.html">Level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="test/level2.html">Level 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="test/level2/level3.html">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="test/level2/level32.html">Also at level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="test3.html">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

If the user navigates to Level 3, based on current page, show:

Home >> Test 2 >> Level 2 >> Level 3

This script will be included in every page, so it works onload.

Comment: Please check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmfWj9G88ew. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following code in the document ready event of the page.

```
var url = "level3.html"; <-- following line shows how to get this from url
//location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var currentItem = $(".items").find("[href$='" + url + "']");
var path = "home";
$(currentItem.parents("li").get().reverse()).each(function () {
    path += "/" + $(this).children("a").text();
});
$(".bredcrumb").html(path);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paj5odk8/)

Incase if you want breadcrumb with navigation links try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paj5odk8/1/)

Comment: Super, this was spot on! I got an extra / after Home, but it's probably just my html, and hence I can work around that. Thank you!

Comment: This is great. I am working on bootstrap breadcrumbs style with this recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to navigate on http request this code may not work well for you.

If you are going to have html pages to navigate via this menu; you may have some code working on load of every html page you have, to build breadcrumb according to that page.

But if you are going to navigate content via ajax you can use this code. And put your content load function inside on click event.

Comment: The javascript I'm thinking about will be working on every load, no ajax will be used.

Comment: Are you building an html site or using any serverside programming that you may pass the current page's info to create the breadcrumb?

Comment: Trying to create an independent top-html that will be included both on applications with serverside programming backend and in a wordpress instance. That's why I'd like it to be javascript. I know one can get the current page with $(location).attr('href'); . So It would be iterating through the ul to find the similar url as the one I'm currently viewing.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpyxcbok/2/ if i got you right this will do.

Comment: Thanks, nice fiddle :) One step closer, but it would not work with the filestructure at hand.