# Javscript to copy to clipboard string formed dinamically from HTML div tree path

Tags: javascript, html, tree

I have a menu with submenus which form a tree of options. It is a list of options of an app, and I need the operator to click the elements and get in the clipboard a string with the path to that element. Here is a sample code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header btn-nivel4" id="mnclA" onclick="copyPath('Menu > Limits')">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mncl" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mncl">
                <strong>Limits</strong>
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="mncl" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="mnclA" data-parent="#omncA">
        <div class="card-body">

            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item btn-nivel5" onclick="copyPath('Menu > Limits > Avaliable limits')">Avaliable limits</li>
                <li class="list-group-item btn-nivel5" onclick="copyPath('Menu > Limits > Adjust limits')">Adjust limits</li>
                <li class="list-group-item btn-nivel5" onclick="copyPath('Menu > Limits > Emergency limit evaluation')">Emergency limit evaluation</li>
                <li class="list-group-item btn-nivel5" onclick="copyPath('Menu > Limits > Confirm limit increase')">Confirm limit increase</li>
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function copyPath(text) {

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);

    }
</script>
```

Notice the problem here: I need to call the javascript funcion every time a new element is clicked, and need to put a line every time with the string I want to copy to clipboard, whici is always the string element with " > " separating the nodes. I need it to be done dinamically, so when I change the tree I don't need to manually put a new line in every element. Example: when clicking on the "Avaliable limits" li, I want to be copied to the clipboard, "Menu > Limits > Avaliable limits". I need it to be similar to every div and list element. How do I do it?

I tried to search about nodes and learn more about HTML and Javascript, but I'm not sure I even know the correct keywords here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is similar to the concept of breadcrumbs - example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dynamic-breadcrumbs-using-javascript/amp/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416842/jquery-dynamic-breadcrumb

Comment: Thanks, that's very similar to what I want and you also gave me new things to search for! I'm not sure tough if I can use jQuery

Comment: For anyone interested, this is the jQuery I managed to pull off to copy the bredcrumbs to the clipboard, but it isn't working in my code.... only in nested lists (<ul>)
`code`
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $bc = $('<div class="card"></div>'),
      $temp = $("<input>");

  $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' > ', $a);
  });
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($bc.text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    return false;
})`code`